# How to delete a node and its object from a TTreeView

Tags: delphi, treeview

I am using Delphi 10 Starter edition.  I am studying how to use Delphi's `TTreeView` component.

Everything works, no issues. The only question I have left is:

After adding an object to a node, what is the right way to delete the item and its object?

Here is my code (see `Button6Click`):

```
type
  TMyNode2 = class
  public
    nom: Integer;
    comm: String;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyNode2: TMyNode2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); // add node
var
  x: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Items.Add(tv1.Selected, Edit1.Text + ' ' + IntToStr(Round(Random(100))));
  x.ImageIndex := 1;
  x.SelectedIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  x.StateIndex := x.ImageIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject); // add child node
var
  x: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Items.AddChild(tv1.Selected, 'Child ' + Edit1.Text + ' ' + IntToStr(Round(Random(100))));
  x.ImageIndex := 2;
  x.SelectedIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  x.StateIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  tv1.Selected.Expand(true);
  x.Selected := true;
  x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); // del node (if not 1st)
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  y := tv1.Items[0];
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> y then
    x.Delete
  else
    ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); // add node (v.2 as object)
var
  x: TTreeNode;
begin
  MyNode2 := TMyNode2.Create;
  MyNode2.nom := Round(Random(1000));
  MyNode2.comm := IntToStr(MyNode2.nom) + ' comment ' + IntToStr(MyNode2.nom);
  x := tv1.Items.AddObject(tv1.Selected, Edit1.Text + ' ' + IntToStr(Round(Random(1000))), Pointer(MyNode2)); 
  x.ImageIndex := 3;
  x.SelectedIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  x.StateIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  tv1.Selected.Expand(true);
  x.Selected := true;
  x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject); // add child node (v.2 as object)
var
  x: TTreeNode;
begin
  MyNode2 := TMyNode2.Create;
  MyNode2.nom := Round(Random(1000));
  MyNode2.comm := IntToStr(MyNode2.nom) + ' child comment ' + IntToStr(MyNode2.nom);
  x := tv1.Items.AddChildObject(tv1.Selected, Edit1.Text + ' ' + IntToStr(Round(Random(1000))), Pointer(MyNode2));
  x.ImageIndex := 4;
  x.SelectedIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  x.StateIndex := x.ImageIndex;
  tv1.Selected.Expand(true);
  x.Selected := true;
  x.Expand(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject); // del node (if not 1st) and "as" object
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  y := tv1.Items[0];
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> y then begin
    //class(x.tMyNode2(node.Data)).Free; // **** // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    x.Delete;
  end else
    ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); // on create - add data 2 1st node
var
  x: TTreeNode;
begin
  MyNode2 := TMyNode2.Create;
  MyNode2.nom := 100001;
  MyNode2.comm := '1st node comment';
  x := tv1.Items[0];
  x.Data := Pointer(MyNode2);
end;

procedure TForm1.tv1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode); // look node prop.
begin
  if Node = nil then
    Caption:='Not select'
  else
  if Node.Data = nil then
    Caption := Format('Nom: %d, Im.Ind: %d', [Integer(Node.Index), Integer(Node.ImageIndex)])
  else
    Caption := Format('Nom: %d, Im.Ind: %d, MyNode.Nom: %d, Comm: %s', [Integer(Node.Index), Integer(Node.ImageIndex), Integer(TMyNode2(node.Data).nom), string(TMyNode2(node.Data).comm)]);
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the TreeView's `OnDeletion` event, which is triggered when a `TTreeNode` is being removed from the tree:

```
procedure TForm1.tv1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  TMyNode2(Node.Data).Free;
  // or simply:
  // TObject(Node.Data).Free;
end;
```

Thus:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
// del node (if not 1st)
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> nil then
  begin
    y := tv1.Items.GetFirstNode;
    if x <> y then
      x.Delete
    else
      ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
// del node (if not 1st) and its object
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> nil then
  begin
    y := tv1.Items.GetFirstNode;
    if x <> y then
      x.Delete
    else
      ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, `Button2Click()` and `Button6Click()` are now identical, so you can remove one of them.  Unless you really want `Button2Click()` to not free the node's object, in which case you can just set `x.Data` to `nil` before calling `x.Delete()` (you are still responsible for keeping track of the object somewhere so you can free it later, or else it will be leaked):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
// del node (if not 1st) but not its object
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> nil then
  begin
    y := tv1.Items.GetFirstNode;
    if x <> y then
    begin
      x.Data := nil; // <-- !!!
      x.Delete;
    end else
      ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
// del node (if not 1st) and its object
var
  x, y: TTreeNode;
begin
  x := tv1.Selected;
  if x <> nil then
  begin
    y := tv1.Items.GetFirstNode;
    if x <> y then
      x.Delete
    else
      ShowMessage('Do not del 1st node!');
  end;
end;
```